# How to kill android app by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kill-process

**I want simulate the situation when my app killed by OS.**

Example: I've hidden my app (by pressing middle circle nav button) and opened any other app, now I need to kill process and observe what would be if I open app from recent opened app list(by pressing right rect nav button).

How I can simulate killing app by OS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply kill your app by using adb.

```bash
adb shell am force-stop <YOUR_PACKAGE>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also find another way in android studio, when I run my app, there is a button "Terminate Application" in the Logcat window

[image]

Comment: Please note that the "Terminate Application" button will move from logcat to the new device monitor soon, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246928842